# Import Multiple Excel Workbook From Specific Folder Into Single Worksheet Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MergeExcels()

Dim Path, FName As String

Path = ""
FName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While File <> ""
    Workbooks.Open File = Path & FName, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(File).Close
    File = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Not a single compile error, but the value doesnt fetching

Comment: Is my code right

Comment: Your code is openning workbooks, copying each worksheet to your main workbook on the second index position. It can be cleaned out, but this should work.

Comment: Could You Provide Me a better solution to run this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are starting with VBA I'd recommend you to use `Option Explicit` on the top of your modules, it will force you to declare all your variables.

On the other hand, when you declare variables like `Dim Path, FName As String` only `FName` will be a `String`, `Path` will be a `Variant` type.

Using variables for workbook and worksheet objects will help you to clean your code.

Also indenting will help your code readability.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeExcels()

    Dim Path As String, FName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Path = ""
    FName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
        Do While FName <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & FName, ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                ws.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            Next ws
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            FName = Dir()
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: Found out your error, you were giving to `FName` the filename, but loping through `FileName`(which is always empty).

Comment: Ty So Much ... But Receiving Compile Error

Comment: I just edited the code, try it out again, if it keeps giving you an error, please point out on which line your code is highlighted.,

Comment: Did you copy just like my example the code? Because you are missing some text.

Answer (score 0):

Merge multiple Excel files in a folder into a single sheet:

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm